# base class, inheritate class sizeof()

Tags: c++, class, sizeof

Why, in the following code, is `sizeof(X) == 4` and `sizeof(Y) == 8`?

Moreover, in the class `X`, why do the member functions not take any memory space?

```
class X {
    int i;
public:
    X() { i = 0; }
    void set(int ii) { i = ii; }
    int read() const { return i; }
    int permute() { return i = i * 47; }
};

class Y : public X {
    int i; // Different from X's i
public:
    Y() { i = 0; }
    int change() {
        i = permute(); // Different name call
        return i;
    }
    void set(int ii) {
        i = ii;
        X::set(ii); // Same-name function call
    }
};


    cout << "sizeof(X) = " << sizeof(X) << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(Y) = " << sizeof(Y) << endl;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects of class `Y` have two integer members; objects of class `X` have one.  Your comments express the fact that `Y`'s `i` is different from `X`'s `i`, so it looks like you already knew the answer.

See http://codepad.org/PZsiyFIk for an example of how an object of class `Y` actually has two `i` members.

Code repeated here:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class X {
  int i;
public:
  X(): i(4) {}
  int getI() {return i;}
};

class Y: public X {
  int i;
public:
  Y(): i(10) {}
  int getMyI() {return i;}
};

int main() {
  Y y;
  cout << y.getI() << ' ' << y.getMyI() << '\n';
}
```

Outputs

```
4 10
```

There is only one object in `main` called `y`.  Note that `y` must have two `i` fields for the output to make sense.

Comment: I copy from a book's code. :)Now I know. but not very clear about how to use these two diff i.

Comment: Added to my answer.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

X is the base class. Has only one data member ie: `int i`. Y is derived from X and has its own and the derived data memebers. ie: two `int i`s.

Answer (score 1):

> Moreover, in the class X, why do the member functions not take any memory space?

I think no one has covered this part yet. A class' member functions aren't stored within the object itself because they belong to the class, not the object. There's no reason to store a copy of the function within each objects, since the code always stays the same.

`sizeof(X)` returns the amount of bytes you need to store an instance of type X, not the entire class.

Furthermore a member function is stored like any other normal c function in memory. It just takes a pointer to the object it's called from:

```
int X::permute() { return i = i * 47; }
...
someX.permute();
```

Turns into:

```
int permute(X* _x) { return _x->i = _x->i * 47; }
...
permute(&someX);
```

The idea of member functions is only an abstraction for us to use. The only thing an objects actually consists of is member variables and maybe a virtual function table.

Answer (score 0):

Size of X is 4 because it has an int i

Size of Y is 8 because of base class i + derived class i

Member functions does not take size unless if you have a virtual function then for storing vpointer it will have 4 bytes.